# Associated Domain feature is only available to users enrolled in Apple Developer Pro

Tags: iphone, xcode

I have a free apple developer account and i try to run an app on my own iPhone in Xcode.

When i try this i get the error: "The 'Associated Domain' feature is only available to users enrolled in Apple Developer Program. Please visit 
https://developer.apple.com/programs/ to enroll.
"

Where can i disable a Associated Domain ? All the capabilities are empty and in the entitlements file are no domains.

UPDATE: Running on the iPhone emulator is working.

Printscreen from the .entitlements file:

[image: entitlements file]

Error:

The 'Associated Domain' feature is only available to users enrolled in Apple Developer Program. Please visit 
https://developer.apple.com/programs/ to enroll.

No profiles for 'nl.*.*.test' were found:  Xcode couldn't find a provisioning profile matching 'nl.*.*.test'.

Code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 10.2'

Comment: did you find a solution?  facing same issue

Comment: No, I have not yet a solution

Answer (score 1):

In the `.entitlements` file, make sure that the Associated Domains array is completely removed. If it is still listed there, even with no domains, Xcode will complain if you don't have a paid developer account.

[Incorrect .entitlements file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z2kuS.png)

Comment: See the update with the screenshot from my file. Its empty.